# How do I limit an ip to be able to submit a form only once every hour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, windows-server-2012-r2

I am currently working on a web project and I want to put in a feedback form. I want an ip to only be able to send feedback in the form only once every e.g. 4 hours.

I can use third party libraries if I need to but I would rather not use them (exception of jQuery).

If you want to see the website, visit [this link](http://damngoodfun.com/)

I have tried researching on stack overflow and on other website but I cannot find a result. I cannot find a method for JS/jQuery, it is mostly just PHP

Thanks

Comment: server side code

Comment: this has to be done in your server code.

Comment: Are you using a database to store the feedback from the user? If so, I can show you an easy workflow for this.

Comment: I dont think this is a genuine problem, here user is only trying to increase visits to his site, a beginner developer also knows he can use session or cookies to solve this type of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using a database you can use the following structure. Have a database table (feedbackTable) and at least 3 columns (IP, feedbackText, feedbackTime- a timestamp of when the feedback was sent).

When the user's form is submitted get the variables you need...

```
$ip=$_POST["ip"];
$feedbackText=$_POST["feedbackText"];
```

Use the information in a query...

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM feedbackTable WHERE IP=:ip AND feedbackTime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOURS) AND NOW()";
// or NOW()-4 hours ... depends on database and version
```

Execute the query. If 0 rows is returned (use rowCount() for PDO prepared statements in PHP) then the feedback text can be added to the database and/or made visible to users. If 1 row is returned tell the user he cannot submit feedback again until the 4 hours is up. 
    It would actually be better to not even make the form visible to the user until the 4 hours since last submission are up. You can do that by "polling" using ajax and jQuery(hide the form after submission, then set an interval - maybe every minute - on the database query script using ajax, when the script come back as saying the 4 ours is up show the form again) ... but that isn't required. The user might get a little miffed if they take the time to fill out feedback and then you tell them you're not taking it because not enough time has elapsed. 
    I would not use local storage to save time requirements because there are ways for the user to alter that information.

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the rate at which a user can do something is best suited to being done on the server. This is why most of the examples that you have found are in PHP. This is because the user can easily change what their machine does, so it is more secure to do this on the server.

If you really want to limit the rate on the client, then here is an outline of how I would do it:

Have a variable in local storage (more about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)) that keeps track of when the user last submitted feedback.

Then, add an event listener to the form submit event. In this event listener, if it has been less than 4 hours since the user last submitted the form, then prevent the form from submitting. You can do this with `ev.preventdefault`. Also, remember to update your variable.